# Vue 3 require files in main.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to upgrade a Vue 2 to Vue 3. In Vue 2, we were able to keep the main.js file fairly organized using requires to import files with different Vue settings. Because of the new Vue and the way of adding things to Vue, I've had to kind of copy and paste everything into the main.js. I haven't been able to figure out the best way to NOT do this. For example:

in Vue 2,

```
// in the main.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

require('./bootstrap/shared')

// in the shared.js (this is the tinier of examples)
import Vue from 'vue'

const permissions = {
  me: null,
  user: null,
}

Vue.prototype.$permissions = permissions
Vue.prototype.$globals = Vue.observable({ site: {} })
```

Now in Vue 3, I had to copy that shared file and just paste it directly into the main so it can be added to the app.

```
import { createApp, h, reactive } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

const app = createApp({
  render: () => h(App),
})


const permissions = {
  me: null,
  user: null,
}

app.config.globalProperties.$permissions = permissions
app.config.globalProperties.$globals = reactive({ site: {} });

app.mount('#app');
```

I've been trying to find a different way of doing this without overloading the main.js but haven't seen a way. I'd love some guidance if anyone has anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create separate file `globals.js` for example and put inside:

```
import { reactive } from 'vue';

export function setupGlobals(app) {
    const permissions = {
        me: null,
        user: null,
    };

    app.config.globalProperties.$permissions = permissions;
    app.config.globalProperties.$globals = reactive({ site: {} });
}
```

Then in your main.js:

```
import { createApp, h } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { setupGlobals } from './globals'

const app = createApp({
    render: () => h(App),
});

setupGlobals(app);

app.mount('#app');
```

Comment: This was brilliant! Thank you for that! I knew there was someway but I couldn't wrap my mind around it.